# jQuery adding text to an element that has not yet loaded

Tags: jquery, load, addclass

Just for context, this is happening in my WordPress Admin Area but it's not really WP specific.

I have a link that, when clicked, creates a new DOM element with a few child elements. I am trying to add a class name to this new element like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">         
    jQuery(document).ready( function($) {                 
        $('tr#post-65 span.inline a.editinline').click(function() {
            $('tr#edit-65').addClass('someclass');
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

So `tr#post-65` always exists but the table row `edit-65` only exists when `a.editinline` is clicked. However, `tr#edit-65` is **not created** by my jQuery above but by WP's own jQuery code which I have no access to.

So, my question is, how can I add a class to an element that is created after my own jQuery block is loaded? Is it possible to detect when element `edit-65` is successfully loaded/created and **only then** add my custom class to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this : As you don't have control over the creation of element, you can do a work around using setInterval and check if element created then set class and exit.

```
jQuery(document).ready( function($) {       
        $('tr#post-65 span.inline a.editinline').click(function() {
           var interval = setInterval(function(){ 
               if($('tr#edit-65').length)
                {  
                   $('tr#edit-65').addClass('someclass');
                   clearInterval(interval );
                }
             }, 500);
        });
    });
```

**[More Information on setInterval()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)**

Comment: Thank you, that works perfectly. And thanks for the additional info link.

Comment: happy to help you :)

Answer (score 1):

Create an interval to check the existance of the element periodically. and clear the interval when done:

```
<script type="text/javascript">         
    jQuery(document).ready( function($) {                 
        $('tr#post-65 span.inline a.editinline').click(function() {
            var int = setInterval(function(){
                   if($('tr#edit-65').length>0)
                       {$('tr#edit-65').addClass('someclass');
                        clearInterval(int);
                       }
             }, 100);

        });
    }); 
</script>
```